# Saved Parse Database into an array called recipes and am now trying to access content within that array

Tags: parse-platform, ios9, xcode7, swift2

I have a database in parse that i have pulled into a swift array. The custom parse object is called `UserRecipe`. The array is called `recipes` and is located in the `viewDidLoad` method. I am trying to set the imageview i have called `recipeImage`, to always access the image of the first element in the array. I do this in the `updateImage` function but am not sure if I have the correct syntax. Also the array seems to be stored only with the `viewDidLoad` method and is not accessible to my `updateImage` function. I'm wondering how to make it global so all functions can access it. Thanks in advance for any help.

The database looks like this:

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Parse
//import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let recipes = [PFObject]?.self

    @IBOutlet var recipeImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //load in all data from Parse custom Object UserRecipe and store it in variable recipes

        var query = PFQuery(className:"UserRecipe")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (recipes: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let recipes = recipes {
                    for recipe in recipes {
                        print(recipe["recipeName"])
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }

        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
        recipeImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        //let tapping = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasTapped:"))
        //recipeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapping)

        recipeImage.userInteractionEnabled = true


        //updateImage()
        //getUserInfo()



    }


    func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {


        //Dragging Animation

        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
        let imageDrag = gesture.view!

        imageDrag.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2 + translation.x, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2 + translation.y - 153)

        let xFromCenter = imageDrag.center.x - self.view.bounds.width / 2 + translation.x

        let scale = min(100 / abs(xFromCenter), 1)


        var rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(xFromCenter / 200)

        var stretch = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, scale, scale)

        imageDrag.transform = stretch


        //determines whether current user has accepted or rejected certain recipes

        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            var acceptedOrRejected = ""

            if imageDrag.center.x < 100 {

                acceptedOrRejected = "rejected"

                print("not chosen")

                //print("not chosen" + object["recipeName"])

            } else if imageDrag.center.x > self.view.bounds.width - 100 {

                acceptedOrRejected = "accepted"
                print("Chosen")
            }

            /*if acceptedOrRejected != "" {

                PFUser.currentUser()?.addUniqueObjectsFromArray([displayedUserId], forKey: acceptedOrRejected)

                PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({

                    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if succeeded {

                    } else {

                        print(error)

                    }

                })



            }*/

            //Resets image position after it has been let go of


            rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)


            stretch = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, 1, 1)

            imageDrag.transform = stretch

            imageDrag.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 153)

            updateImage()


        }
    }

    func updateImage() {
        recipeImage.image = recipes["image"][0]

    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not across Parse but if I were you these are things I would try,

1. Set a breakpoint in

```
    func updateImage() {
    // set breakpoint here and check whether recipes contains any data.
        recipeImage.image = recipes["image"][0]
    }
```

2. Replace the code as shown below,

```
    //replace
    recipes["image"][0] 
    //to
    recipes[0]["image"]
```